# initWithArray doesn't work with NSArray property

Tags: iphone

In viewDidLoad, I have:

```
NSArray *selectedPeople = [[selectedObject people] allObjects];
NSArray *peeps = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:selectedPeople];
```

This works just fine, but when I use an NSArray that was declared in my properties it doesn't:

```
NSArray *selectedPeople = [[selectedObject people] allObjects];
people = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:selectedPeople];
```

The program crashes and says that:

```
[People isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6031910
```

I'm using CoreData and selectedPeople holds People objects. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: It doesn't look like the code you've posted and the crash you've pasted are related. Can you paste the backtrace and show where it relates to the code in your question, please?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. I'm apologize for posting this. I didn't realize I was sending messages to people elsewhere. I believe I was returning values that were not the correct data type. Wow. I need to go to bed. Thanks Graham and Zeppomedio. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Just as a side note, instead of doing `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:someArr]`, you can simply do `[someArr copy]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Core Data setters for a collection of objects take a set and not an array.

You could try the following:

```
self.people = [[NSSet setWithArray:selectedPeople];
```

Answer (score 1):

Is people one of your properties? Did you mean to do:

```
self.people = [[NSArray ...
```

instead?